# Postfix - relaying specific email addresses within a mydestination domain

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

Having some issues trying to get something working on postfix.

That is, I have a domain `abc.com` which is a destination domain on my postfix server `1.2.3.4`, it hosts mailboxes for addresses in this domain locally by default - straight-forward.

However, I would like to be able to "relay" specific email addresses from within this same domain (say: `userx@abc.com`) to another postfix server `[5.6.7.8]:2525` - yet still retaining the original ability of being able to deliver mail to all other addresses `*@abc.com` locally on my original postfix server `1.2.3.4`.

Is anyone able to advise how I can go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Cont.

Thanks tater, I've actually gone with something similar so far, but still have one issue.

So I have `transport` file:

```
userx@abc.com  relay:[5.6.7.8]:2525
*@abc.com  local
```

And `main.cf`:

```
relay_domains = abc.com
```

This config sends to the relay perfect as I want, but any other addresses (in the wildcard scope) do not get delivered as they try to go straight back out the default relay server (another server altogether), where-as instead I'd like them to hit `/etc/aliases` or a local mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use transport maps.  In `main.cf`, have a line like

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

and then in the `transport` file,

```
userx@abc.com  smtp:5.6.7.8:2525
```

This is searched in most- to least-specific order, so if you wanted to specify something else for `abc.com` you would do it like

```
userx@abc.com  smtp:5.6.7.8:2525
abc.com  smtp:1.2.3.4:25
```

but `local` transport is the default, so if that's what you want a second line is not needed.

Comment: Thanks tater, I've actually gone with something similar so far, but still have one issue.

So I have `transport` file:
`userx@abc.com  relay:[5.6.7.8]:2525
*@abc.com  local`

And `main.cf`:
`relay_domains = abc.com`

This config sends to the relay perfect as I want, but any other addresses (in the wildcard scope) do not get delivered as they try to go straight back out the default relay server (another server altogether)

I'll add this as an update above so it's easier to read.

Comment: any other ideas about this one? Provided an update in the original post.